# Android - Listener for newly started application

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

Is there a way to implement a service that would listen for started applications? 
Say - "now the Browser is started" or something like that?

Comment: for your application or any application on the android device ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for an [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) ?

Regards,
 Stéphane